# Problem with Schema recognition in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make a login page and send the info to a Mongodb database. But I'm running into a reference error and have no idea why.
My Mongoose Schema is as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var validateEmail = function(email) {
    var re = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    return re.test(email)
};

var userSchema = new Schema({
    full_name: { type: String,  required: [true, 'Full name must be provided'] },
    email:    {
        type: String,
        Required:  'Email address cannot be left blank.',
        validate: [validateEmail, 'Please fill a valid email address'],
        match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/, 'Please fill a valid email address'],
        index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}
    },
    password: { type: String , required: [true,  'Password cannot be left blank']},
    dob: { type: Date , required: [true, 'Date of birth must be provided']},
    country: { type: String , required: [true, 'Country cannot be left blank.']},
    gender: { type: String , required: [true, 'Gender must be provided']},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema);
```

When i try running the following code i get the message:

**var User = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema);

ReferenceError: userSchema is not defined**

````
var mongoose  = require('mongoose');
var crypto = require('crypto'), hmac, signature;
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');
const { matchedData, sanitize } = require('express-validator/filter');

var User = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema);

/* POST user registration page. */
router.post('/register',[

  check('full_name','Name cannot be left blank')
      .isLength({ min: 1 }),

  check('email')
      .isEmail().withMessage('Please enter a valid email address')
      .trim()
      .normalizeEmail()
      .custom(value => {
        return findUserByEmail(value).then(User => {
          //if user email already exists throw an error
        })
      }),
  check('password')
      .isLength({ min: 5 }).withMessage('Password must be at least 5 chars long')
      .matches(/\d/).withMessage('Password must contain one number')
      .custom((value,{req, loc, path}) => {
        if (value !== req.body.cpassword) {
          // throw error if passwords do not match
          throw new Error("Passwords don't match");
        } else {
          return value;
        }
      }),
  check('gender','Please select gender')
      .isLength({ min: 1 }),
  check('dob','Date of birth cannot be left blank')
      .isLength({ min: 1 }),

  check('country','Country cannot be left blank')
      .isLength({ min: 1 }),

  check('terms','Please accept our terms and conditions').equals('yes'),
], function(req, res, next) {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {

    res.json({status : "error", message : errors.array()});
  } else {
    hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha1", 'auth secret');
    var encpassword = '';
    if(req.body.password){
      hmac.update(req.body.password);
      encpassword = hmac.digest("hex");
    }
    var document = {
      full_name:   req.body.full_name,
      email:       req.body.email,
      password:    encpassword,
      dob:         req.body.dob,
      country:     req.body.country,
      gender:      req.body.gender,
      calorie:     req.body.calorie,
      salt:        req.body.salt
    };

    var user = new User(document);
    user.save(function(error){
      console.log(user);
      if(error){
        throw error;
      }
      res.json({message : "Data saved successfully.", status : "success"});
    });
  }
});
function findUserByEmail(email){
  if(email){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      User.findOne({ email: email })
          .exec((err, doc) => {
            if (err) return reject(err)
            if (doc) return reject(new Error('This email already exists. Please enter another email.'))
            else return resolve(email)
          })
    })
  }
}
module.exports = router;```

Any ideas why the schema can't be found. (Im new to node.js and webframeworks)
````

Comment: Because `userSchema` is not defined in your second file. Why are you recreating the `User` model in the other file?

Comment: Because I can't make new Users if I don't do that

Comment: Did you require that schema file?